# How to print out the cookie value in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a website for number guessing. The overview of the website is shown as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDrJP.png)

In setCookiesA.php, there are two cookies called c(color) and maxNum(the maximum number of guesses) stored. After storing the cookies, player will be redirected to GuessingA.php. The code is shown as follows:

```
<?php
    setCookie("c",$_GET["itemChosen"],time()+(86400 * 365), "/");
    setCookie("maxNo",$_GET["noGuess"],time()+(86400 * 365), "/");
    header("Location:GuessingA.php");
?>
```

After going to GuessingA.php, the cookie value color should be printed out in the sentence "You have chosen the ??? channel for  guessing" (??? represents the color) The partially completed code is shown below.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION["ans"]))  {

   } else {

   }
   $continue = true;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> Guessing game </title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Welcome </h1>
   <p> You have chosen the $_COOKIE[c] channel for  guessing</p>

   <h2> The answer </h2>




   <form method="post" action="<?php print htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
   <p>
      Type your guess here: <input type="text" name="guess" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit"
         <?php if (!$continue) { print("disabled=\"disabled\""); } ?>
      />
   </p>
   </form>

   <h2> Your guess: </h2>



</body>
</html>
```

I considered using javascript function found in google to get the cookie value, but it did not work.

```
function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The function created by myself to print out the color in the body part.

```
function change()
    {
        var color=readCookie(c);
        color.innerHTML="You have chosen the " +color+" channel for  guessing";
    }
```

How to get the cookie value? Thank you very much.

Comment: I mean it's so basic and easy to find... https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp Why come straight here instead of researching, googling?

Comment: `readCookie(c);` you haven't setup a `c` variable, unless it is in a higher scope and you arent showing it (which you should)

Comment: In my program, there are two cookies stored, the color and the maxNum. Therefore, I would like to know if I can get the color only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <p> You have chosen the $_COOKIE[c] channel for  guessing</p>
> ```

You are just writing text. There's no PHP code there.

Look at what you did here:

> ```
>  <form method="post" action="<?php print htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
> ```

Do that!

```
<p> You have chosen the <?php print htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['c']); ?> channel for  guessing</p>
```